# Publishing the XCFramework

Tags: ios, swift, xcframework, modularization

I want to modularise my codebase to distribute it like third party libraries. I followed the [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/17753301-creating-a-framework-for-ios) for the same. So far I have been able to split the code into three modules (Networking, Core & Home). The problem is occurred while [archiving](https://www.raywenderlich.com/17753301-creating-a-framework-for-ios#toc-anchor-009) the XCFramework with given command - [image: commands] I was facing this  error -

```
:10:8: error: no such module 'Alamofire'
import Alamofire
       ^

Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 (in target 'Networking' from project 'Networking')
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'Networking' from project 'Networking')
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'Networking' from project 'Networking')
(3 failures)
```

So I did some R&D and excluded the arm64 and x86_64  for simulator architecture both from your main Project and the Pod project. [image: excluded]Error has gone and archiving was successful. But the **xcarchive file created by the command, having only size of 21KB.**

Still I tried to generate the XCFramework for simulator and iOS device with the following command -

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework './build/Networking.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/Networking.framework' \
-framework './build/Networking.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/Networking.framework' \
-output './build/Networking.xcframework'
```

As expected, I got the error -
"unable to read the file at '/Users/vinodkr/Documents/GitHub/channel-partners-ios/Frameworks/Networking/build/Networking.framework-iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/Networking.framework/Networking'"

NOTE :- Device specification

- macOS Monterey, 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
- xcode Version 13.1 (13A1030d)

More Information  -

1. I tried the article with brand new project without Pods in it. It worked perfectly fine.
2. I am consuming 'Alamofire' with a warning - "Module 'Alamofire' was not compiled with library evolution support; using it means binary compatibility for 'Networking' can't be guaranteed".